# Measuring area covered by linestring

Tags: sql, geometry, sql-server, st-geometry

I have a trajectory given by GPS which I store as a `ST_LineString()` and I'd like to know the area covered by the line string. I know the `"width"` of the trajectory, but I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

I thought the following steps might do what I want.

1. break line string into an array of two-point segments (simple lines)
2. create a rectangle from the two-point-line and width
3. call `st_unionaggr()` over all rectangles to create one polygon and then call `st_area()` on it

[image: example]

So my question is: Is there an effective way to create a rectangle from given line and width? And if so, do you think this solution is viable or is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: What if you consider a buffer `ST_Buffer()` with round end caps and joins?

Comment: Why not just buffer the line and use that polygon?

Comment: Thanks for the hint; that would do exactly what I need. Unfortunately I run an SAP SQL Anywhere server so I checked the manual and it says this is a list of unsupported methods:

ST_Buffer, ST_LocateAlong, ST_LocateBetween, ST_Segmentize, ST_Simplify,  ST_Distance_Spheroid , ST_Length_Spheroid

Comment: What about ST_ConvexHull?

Comment: `ST_ConvexHull()` might work as a good approximation in some cases, I'll try to work with it since it's probably the best option for now. In the meantime I'll try to force my company to upgrade the db server to a newer version which already supports method `st_buffer()`. I'm not interested in implementing _Minkowski_ _sum_ on my own really :) Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

As Taras and Ian Turton suggested, function `ST_Buffer()` is the best solution for this problem, even though my version of the db server doesn't support it yet.

Comment: There are other tools also available to create buffer and calculate area, that doesn't need a db server. Which programming language are you using?